# how to verify facial feature by winbio API?

Tags: c++, biometrics

So far i have implement a test function like this

```
    hr = WinBioEnumBiometricUnits(
        WINBIO_TYPE_FACIAL_FEATURES,        // Type of biometric unit
        &unitSchema,                    // Array of unit schemas
        &unitCount);                   // Count of unit schemas

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioEnumBiometricUnits failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    hr = WinBioOpenSession(
        WINBIO_TYPE_FACIAL_FEATURES,    // Service provider
        WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
        WINBIO_FLAG_DEFAULT,        // Configuration and access
        NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
        0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
        WINBIO_DB_DEFAULT,                       // Database ID
        &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
    );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        goto e_Exit;
    }

retry:
    // Locate the biometric sensor and retrieve a WINBIO_IDENTITY object.
    wprintf_s(L"\n Calling WinBioIdentify - Swipe finger on sensor...\n");
    hr = WinBioIdentify(
        sessionHandle,              // Session handle
        &unitId,                    // Biometric unit ID
        &identity,                  // User SID
        &subFactor,                 // Finger sub factor
        &rejectDetail               // Rejection information
    );
```

i test it on a windows10 laptop, which has a camera on it that i can logon OS by facial feature via windows hello, `WinBioEnumBiometricUnits` success and the count is 1, `WinBioOpenSession` success too, but `WinBioIdentify` failed and the error code is `WINBIO_E_INVALID_OPERATION-0x8009802C`, MSDN said that windows biometric framwork support `WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT` only for now, the doc last update in 2018, it has been three years, does any buddy know that whether MS has support `WINBIO_TYPE_FACIAL_FEATURES` type or not, or maybe there is other API for facial feature verify, please let me know, thanks very much in advance.

Comment: if online MSDN says they don't support then they don't, unfortunately. I think you are referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbiomet/winbio-biometric-type-constants.

Comment: @vish, yes, it is that link. thank you for reply.

Comment: Yes but since Windows hello does work with supported WebCams it has to be a way.

Comment: I did it. You have to be in async mode. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1156801/FingerPrintf-A-small-library-for-quick-usage-of-th

Answer (score 0):

I found the way.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1156801/FingerPrintf-A-small-library-for-quick-usage-of-th

You have to open the framework in Async Mode, call [WinBioMonitorPresence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbiomonitorpresence) and then receive WINBIO_ASYNC_RESULT in your message loop to see the status of the camera.